# Apache2, Node and Pm2 Project deployment issue

Tags: node.js, api, apache2, pm2, apache2.4

**I use Linode server (Dedicated CUP 4 core with Ram 8) but the server is does not work well.**

The server response too long time when pm2 app memory reach out above 100mb.
It is happing on this condition.

[image]

**Is it require to upgrade my server? (Ram 16 8Core ..)**

**Is it require to change a config in Apache2?**

**Is it require to change a config in Node?**

**Is it require to change a config in PM2?**

**What should I do?**

Comment: Can you provide result of the `free -h` command?

Comment: Also why is the memory increasing? because of increasing connections? If not because  increasing connections, you hsould have a memory leak.

Comment: @Alaindeseine The result for `free -h`  is [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/135cW2GHB-uFZSQFCMe_1WZJbzdb71iyS/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: And what your pm2 process logs tell? Have you any errors in your PM2 error logs file?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "the server start hanging"? As per your screenshot pm2 process are not errored

Comment: My app is lottery numbers result live app.  So, all of users ( about 10 k ) are open and seeing on my app from 3:00 PM to 4:30 PM. After that, every users have gone from my app. PM2's mem is having around 90 mb in normal time. Is it memory leak? Lottery time memory is having around 110 mb and my server is very hanging in that time.

Comment: So when you tell "the server start hanging" you say that because users take time to get response from server?
I don't think memory is the problem as your free ok. Just try the free commande when you server seems to hang, but i guess it will be nearly the same.

Comment: You say server hang between 3:00 and 4:00 pm. Is the server hanging during 90 minutes? or jsute a fem minutes during 3:00 and 4:00 pm?

Comment: PM2 log also fine. There is no error. Just only lagging in lottery time. I think that I have requiring to fix a configuration to allow for more RAM usage. Now my pm2 is using just only around 110mb memory but my server is so lagging.

Comment: @Alaindeseine Sorry for my bad writing skill, I do not mean "server start hanging", I mean that the hanging start when the memory reach out around 110mb.